# firefox webdriver showing error message your firefox profile cannot be loaded code given below

Tags: firefox

I am getting a the following error msg when I start executing the firefox driver

" Your firefox profile cannot be loaded it may be missing or inaccessible"

```
File F= new File("C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles");
        FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile(F);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
```

Regards
PP

Answer (score 1):

use these command using cmd in ubuntu
`sudo chown -R nirdesh:nirdesh ./.mozilla/`
`sudo chown -R nirdesh:nirdesh ./.cache/`